# Domains with no name servers?

Tags: dns, top-level-domains, dns-servers, nameserver

I have a few ccTLDs (.my) domains and I've just realised that there is no name servers for them at all. I wonder how that is even possible? Did the vendor whom I bought the domains from do something nasty?
I normally assume that once I buy a domain, there would be at least name servers (without any additional charges) available.

Having no name servers also means the the domains are not parked with the registrar or the registrar cannot make money from them (big registrars such as GoDaddy makes loads of money from parked domains, don't you agree with me?) so this is really suspicous

Comment: You mean you can't edit the nameservers at all or simply that there are no default name server entries after purchase? That latter doesn't seem to be a very big deal, just edit them nameservers to whatever you'd like. If it is the former, maybe you can edit the A records instead?

Comment: Hi @JoshMountain, it's the latter. The vendor told there are default name servers but who.is show me absolutely no DNS records at all :(

Answer (score 1):

Your registrar doesn't necessarily provide the nameservers.

You can use services like Zoneedit or Amazon's Route 53 to host your zone files and then those now become the Nameservers that you must enter at your registrar's website. These services are only a few dollars per year, tops.

Answer (score 0):

Every domain name that is registered needs to have atleast 2 nameservers assigned to it at the time of registration. These nameservers need to be valid.

The minimum number is 2 and the maximum number of nameservers that a domain name can have is 13.

Please log-in to the Domain control panel provided by your registrar and update the nameservers(either to point to your hosting space or to a parked page).

You can park your domain for free or redirect it to a different website in case you do not have a hosting package associated with the domain name.

There are various companies like www.afternic.com, www.sedo.com that provide domain parking and monetization facilities.

Also, make sure that the domain names were registered.